# Button in the base template to switch between locations

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a base.html template which lets me choose between shops- I want to use this setting to save a product in relationship to it's location.

I already implemented a middleware that gives me a list of all shops for a logged in user and the current shop (is this a smart way?):

```
from .models import Shop

class ActiveShopMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
    
        shops = Shop.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
        request.current_shop = shops[0]
        request.shops = shops        
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

I create products using a form, and I want to add the current shop information to that. I do this by handing initial data to the form:

```
def get_initial(self):
    return {"shop": self.request.current_shop.id
```

**I want to be able to switch between shops like in the screenshot:**

[image]

I tried this in base template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %} 
    {% if request.num_shops > 1 %}
        <div class="dropdown" aria-labelledby="userMenu"> 
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle mr-2" type="button" id="dropdownMenu0" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">shop: {{ request.current_shop }}</button>
                <form method="post" action="">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    {% for shop in request.shops %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="tessst" value="{{ shop.id }}">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/">{{ shop }}</a>
                    {% endfor %}    
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endif %}
```

I want to get the `shop_id` variable in my index view:

```
def index(request):
    shop_id = request.POST["tessst"]
```

Is this an ok approach? I wanted to avoid having an additional parameter in my urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's better that you generate this shops datas in form . i mean you send this data to front from django fom class.
e.g:
. you can create custom form field and then every form generate this shop field for user. and then in your view you can handle this data .
. also you can create custom model field but it depends on your project .

Comment: Not sure you read my question correctly (or I maybe did not ask clearly enough): I have no problem in saving the shop in the data (I can get the current active shop by calling `request.current_shop`) - I just can't switch between the shops right now.

Comment: you should change your button to input ( like select box ) and move it to "form" element ! then you can get the shop id after user select the shop from list.